# Jquery .validate misbehaving (Not always working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm trying to create some validation for a from. Fairly simple, there is 3 input fields where I want to make sure that they are not empty.

Overall it seems to work, BUT - I've run into a problem which I don't know how to fix. 
First, to show how it looks: (Dang it, I don't have rep enough to post pictures. I hope someone don't mind looking at the links.)

How it looks before validation:
(Urgh, only two links) Basically the same as valid but without the green border.

With valid input: http://i.gyazo.com/dd7b9aa274b01667abe1f86991caf5d9.png

Now, the problem; If I start with the first field, then goes to the next and then the last WITHOUT clicking out of the inputs, it will pass as it should. But if I click back into input field two and delete the input (which would mean that it's false), it still shows as valid.

How it looks after I've done the previous: http://i.gyazo.com/c232594eaf9dea1625946a2c9275586f.png

**Now, for the code**

The HTML:

```
<form id="modal-form">
   <div class="fieldcheck priceModelInput">
      <label>1 week</label>
      <div class="input-group med-input">
         <input id="WeekOneInput" type="number" min="0" value="" />
         <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="icon-money"></i>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="fieldcheck priceModelInput">
      <label>2 weeks</label>
      <div class="input-group med-input">
         <input id="WeekTwoInput" type="number" min="0" value="" />
         <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="icon-money"></i>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="fieldcheck priceModelInput">
      <label>Per Day</label>
      <div class="input-group med-input">
         <input id="DayInput" type="number" min="0" value="" />
         <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="icon-money"></i>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

The Script:

```
$('#modal-form').validate({
   rules: {
      WeekOneInput: {
         minlength: 1,
         required: true
      },
      WeekTwoInput: {
         minlength: 1,
         required: true
      },
      DayInput: {
         minlength: 1,
         required: true
      }
   },
   errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      error.appendTo(element.parent());
   }
});

//Tried this function to extra check it but without succes.
$('#WeekOneInput, #WeekTwoInput, #DayInput').on('focusout', function () {
   if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) $(this).valid();
});
```

So.. Do anyone have an idea why is's acting like this? And how to avoid it?

Kind Regards

Naoness.

Comment: Can you provide the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with example?

Comment: Oh right of course! On the way.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kvtqzp0s/ , but I've not really used the fiddle before, so It's not working at all. Might be because the project I'm working with is using Bootstrap MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `name` to `input`s solves the problem partially. Actually typing correct value and then removing it still produces weird behaviour (not showing error), but this kind of behaviour presents even in [docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/minlength-method/). But at least validation for this works during clicking on `submit`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvtqzp0s/3/).

```
<input id="WeekOneInput" name="WeekOneInput" type="number" min="0" value="" />

<input id="WeekTwoInput" name="WeekTwoInput" type="number" min="0" value="" />

<input id="DayInput" name="DayInput" type="number" min="0" value="" />
```